# how to filter in select dropdown with isotipe.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

How can I change this example to dropdown the filter? my knowledge with almost zero in jquery.

> "https://codepen.io/Igorxp5/pen/ojJLQE"

Comment: We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out the anther example of codepen. It's resolve your problem of filter in select dropdown with isotope and also its work fine.

The link of select dropdown with isotope :

> https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/jubmr

You can check multiple filter also link give below :

> https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/GBJERB

```js
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
// filter functions
var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt( number, 10 ) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -ium
  ium: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    return name.match( /ium$/ );
  }
};
// bind filter on select change
$('.filters-select').on( 'change', function() {
  // get filter value from option value
  var filterValue = this.value;
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
  $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

select {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* ---- isotope ---- */

.grid {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

/* clear fix */
.isotope:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .element-item ---- */

.element-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #888;
  color: #262524;
}

.element-item > * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element-item .name {
  position: absolute;

  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.element-item .symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.element-item .number {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 5px;
}

.element-item .weight {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 76px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.element-item.alkali          { background: #F00; background: hsl(   0, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.alkaline-earth  { background: #F80; background: hsl(  36, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.lanthanoid      { background: #FF0; background: hsl(  72, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.actinoid        { background: #0F0; background: hsl( 108, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.transition      { background: #0F8; background: hsl( 144, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.post-transition { background: #0FF; background: hsl( 180, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.metalloid       { background: #08F; background: hsl( 216, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.diatomic        { background: #00F; background: hsl( 252, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.halogen         { background: #F0F; background: hsl( 288, 100%, 50%); }
.element-item.noble-gas       { background: #F08; background: hsl( 324, 100%, 50%); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<h1>Isotope - filtering with select</h1>

<p>
<select class="filters-select">
  <option value="*">show all</option>
  <option value=".metal">metal</option>
  <option value=".transition">transition</option>
  <option value=".alkali, .alkaline-earth">alkali and alkaline-earth</option>
  <option value=":not(.transition)">not transition</option>
  <option value=".metal:not(.transition)">metal but not transition</option>
  <option value="numberGreaterThan50">number > 50</option>
  <option value="ium">name ends with &ndash;ium</option>
</select>
</p>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">80</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Te</p>
    <p class="number">52</p>
    <p class="weight">127.6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Bismuth</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Bi</p>
    <p class="number">83</p>
    <p class="weight">208.980</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Lead</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pb</p>
    <p class="number">82</p>
    <p class="weight">207.2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Gold</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Au</p>
    <p class="number">79</p>
    <p class="weight">196.967</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Potassium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">K</p>
    <p class="number">19</p>
    <p class="weight">39.0983</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Sodium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Na</p>
    <p class="number">11</p>
    <p class="weight">22.99</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cadmium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Cd</p>
    <p class="number">48</p>
    <p class="weight">112.411</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkaline-earth metal " data-category="alkaline-earth">
    <h3 class="name">Calcium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ca</p>
    <p class="number">20</p>
    <p class="weight">40.078</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Rhenium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Re</p>
    <p class="number">75</p>
    <p class="weight">186.207</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Thallium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Tl</p>
    <p class="number">81</p>
    <p class="weight">204.383</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Antimony</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Sb</p>
    <p class="number">51</p>
    <p class="weight">121.76</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cobalt</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Co</p>
    <p class="number">27</p>
    <p class="weight">58.933</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item lanthanoid metal inner-transition " data-category="lanthanoid">
    <h3 class="name">Ytterbium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Yb</p>
    <p class="number">70</p>
    <p class="weight">173.054</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item noble-gas nonmetal " data-category="noble-gas">
    <h3 class="name">Argon</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ar</p>
    <p class="number">18</p>
    <p class="weight">39.948</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item diatomic nonmetal " data-category="diatomic">
    <h3 class="name">Nitrogen</h3>
    <p class="symbol">N</p>
    <p class="number">7</p>
    <p class="weight">14.007</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Uranium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">U</p>
    <p class="number">92</p>
    <p class="weight">238.029</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Plutonium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pu</p>
    <p class="number">94</p>
    <p class="weight">(244)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for answering, the problem is that I don't know how to implement paging, that's why I found that example with paging but I can't find one that has pagination and dropdown together.